# What media player can I use in order to play encrypted media send over UDP, with my own SK

Tags: encryption, udp, vlc, broadcasting

I am trying to broadcast videos over LAN. The catch is that I want the receiving end to decrypt the ciphertext using a SK (secret key) that I will provide.

I have done some research and found out that I can use VLC's source code and manipulate it so that it will do so.

Now, I want every client to be able to play the video I am broadcasting, what is required by the client in order to be able to do so? can I add my own version of VLC to an HTML file so that the client doesn't need to download any software?

Maybe I am missing something and there's a more simple way to get it done, if so - I'd appreciate your advice.

Thanks a lot in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Look into DRM and common encryption.

Comment: Most browsers support some kind of DRM solution. For example in Firefox, I have both an Adobe (Primetime) and a Google (Widevine) content decryption module as a plugin. Anyway, your question is really too broad to be answered in a good manner. Try to reduce your questions to a manageable scope.

Comment: use html5 video if you want broad compat without installs